# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource from [Module \"com.ibm.db2\"

Tags: jboss, db2

I am using Jboss EAP 7.2 and trying to add a new XA Datasource. I am using db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar in com.ibm.db2 folder in jboss/modules/.

{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.data-source.ds_km_repos_xa" => "WFLYJCA0033: Error during the deployment of ds_km_repos_xa
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: WFLYJCA0030: unable to deploy
Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.OperationFailedException: WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource [ "WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource" ]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource from [Module "com.ibm.db2" from local module loader @475530b9 (finder: local module finder @1d057a39 (roots: /dnb/opt/jboss/modules,/dnb/opt/jboss/modules/system/layers/base))]"}}}}}}}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with a correct class name:
`com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource`

Your error message shows an incorrect class name.

Comment: Yes, i agree and i had given the com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource name at the time of creation the XA Datasource but in the error it is showing the wrong class name. To resolve this class name issue, i have selected the custom at the time of creating XA DataSource and now, it is accepting the correct class name. Thanks for your quick find ing and sharing the input.

Comment: To Resolve this type of class issues, in Jboss EAP 7 when creating the XA DataSource for DB2, please select "Custom" as Template in place of  selecting IBM DB2 and provide the class name manually. Thanks.